# How to repair corrupt DLL in laptop that won't boot

Tags: windows-8, boot, file-corruption

My laptop (Acer Aspire M5-581TG, Windows 8.1 x64) had some bad sectors which I recovered by doing `chkdsk /R`. This showed that `C:\Windows\system32\d3d11.dll` had the bad sectors in it, so I renamed that file (while in the recovery console's command prompt) to avoid Windows trying to load it.

However, now my lapstop still won't boot. What actually happens is weird, when it gets to where the login screen, the screen stays black for about 20 seconds and then the login screen flashes up for 1 second, then it goes back to black again (can't seem to acheieve anything by clicks/keypresses during this either).

I'd like to repair `d3d11.dll` - how can I do this?  I don't have a non-corrupted copy of it, so far as I'm aware.

I have tried "System Restore" from the boot menu but it failed (code 0x80070005 - An unspecified error occurred during System Restore.). I thought this feature would repair any corrupted system DLLs but it didn't even seem to be attempting that.

NB. It'd be great if there were some way to execute `sfc /scannow` or equivalent from the recovery console; however doing it from the recovery console's command prompt fails when an error message that a repair is pending.

Comment: did you repeatedly run chkdsk until it came up clean, or just once?

Comment: Sounds like your disk has bought the farm if you will and most likely has more bad sectors that cannot be recovered.  Suggestion is to attempt to backup all that you can NOW and reinstall the system and then restore those parts you need.

Comment: @Tetsujin just once. It's improved since running chkdsk (prior to that I just got black screen instead of login screen)

Comment: @mdpc yes but it'd be nice to get it running again in the meantime

Comment: If the drive may be dying, clone it now. if you think it's an isolated incident, run chkdsk repeatedly til it runs clean, then attempt to fix the problem. chkdsk is not very good at recursive fixes.

Comment: from your edit - 0x80070005 is access denied. A bit more Googling tells me that's not an essential system file & the machine should boot without it, so you didn't find the root of the issue yet.

Comment: Looks like I might be stuck with doing a System Refresh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot from a Windows 8 DVD, [go to the repair options](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/pro-tip-use-an-optical-recovery-drive-in-windows-81/) and open a CMD prompt and first UNDO all pending operations with this command:

```
DISM /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions /ScratchDir:C:\
```

Now try to boot. If this still fails, go again to the repair options and run this command:

```
sfc /SCANNOW /OFFBOOTDIR=c:\ /OFFWINDIR=c:\windows
```

to repair system files.

Comment: `sfc` said it found things but couldn't repair them. The log file had some more 0x80070005 errors regarding loading offline registry; although it only seemed to create a log once per reboot.  I've started a System Refresh now

Comment: the refresh removes all desktop applications. But did this work or do you still have issues?

Comment: have you run a SMART check before? Do tools like this (http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html) show any issues?

Comment: Yeah, the C5 is at 18 now (was 8 the other day). No doubt that HD is in trouble, I just want to keep it operational until I can get a new one.

Comment: running again now (chkdsk took 7 hours...)

Comment: C5 = Current Pending Sector Count, so yeah the drive could fail the next weeks (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes)